# How to remove the clicked element parent?

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svkyp55h/1/).

HTML:

```
<div class="myactivelabelsWrap">
   <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-themed-content">
      <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit ui-icon-minus">Home <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon ui-link"></a><span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span></a></h3>
      <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit" aria-hidden="false">
         <ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL ui-listview">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <li class="labellist ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child">
               <div class="leftlable">
                  <h4>Rayalaseema Ruchulu</h4>
                  <p>Area Name,  <b>Phone:</b> +91 99890 11223</p>
                  <p><b>Timings:</b> 11am - 2pm</p>
                  <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 250/-  Delivery Charges Free</p>
                  <label class="label-red label-wrap">Close</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightlable">
                  <a href="#" class="ui-link removerestaurant" id="1">Remove</a>
               </div>
            </li>
            <li class="labellist ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">
               <div class="leftlable">
                  <h4>Rayalaseema Ruchulu</h4>
                  <p>Area Name,  <b>Phone:</b> +91 99890 11223</p>
                  <p><b>Timings:</b> 11am - 2pm</p>
                  <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 250/-  Delivery Charges Free</p>
               </div>
               <div class="rightlable">
                  <a href="#" class="ui-link removerestaurant" id="2" >Remove</a>
               </div>
            </li>
            <li class="labellist ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-last-child">
               <div class="leftlable">
                  <h4>Rayalaseema Ruchulu</h4>
                  <p>Area Name,  <b>Phone:</b> +91 99890 11223</p>
                  <p><b>Timings:</b> 11am - 2pm</p>
                  <p class="minOrder">Min. Order Rs. 250/-  Delivery Charges Free</p>
               </div>
               <div class="rightlable">
                  <a href="#" class="ui-link removerestaurant" id="3">Remove</a>
               </div>
            </li>
            <div class="label-BtnWrap"><button class="icon-plus btn btn-c ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Add More</button></div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerestaurant', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    deletefromDatabase(id);
});

function deletefromDatabase(id)
{
    $(this).closest('.labellist').remove();
}
```

How can I remove the clicked element `.labellist` parent?

Comment: Why do you expect that `$(this)` in the `deletefromDatabase` refers to the clicked element?  You call `deletefromDatabase` directly as of that it's context is `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this` is not correct when you call `deletefromDatabase`. pass the element instead (for now).

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/svkyp55h/2/

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerestaurant', function(event ) {

 var id = $(this).attr('id');

    deletefromDatabase(this);
});


function deletefromDatabase(element)
{
    $(element).closest('.labellist').remove();
}
```

The alternative is to put the one line of delete code in the first handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerestaurant', function(event ) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).closest('.labellist').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank  you very much , this one works very very fine .

Answer (score 0):

For removing from DOM, you can simply traverse to closest li element and then remove it in click event itself. you don't  need to write separate function for it:

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.removerestaurant', function(event ) {
     $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: The original code selector was identical (as `labellist` *is* a class on the `LI`). The problem was the scope of `this` when calling their function.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: agree. but isn't it unnecessary to write seprate function while you are having the context in click to delete it.

Comment: Also covered. Simply pointing out you had not explained your actual fix (which was to move the code into the click handler)